# PicklingError: Could not serialize object: and IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\PysparkSetup\spark\python\pyspark\serializers.py:458, in CloudPickleSerializer.dumps(self, obj)
    457 try:
--> 458     return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
    459 except pickle.PickleError:
File C:\PysparkSetup\spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py:73, in dumps(obj, protocol, buffer_callback)
     70 cp = CloudPickler(
     71     file, protocol=protocol, buffer_callback=buffer_callback
     72 )
---> 73 cp.dump(obj)
     74 return file.getvalue()
```

```py
df3.select("col_explode").rdd.map(lambda x:x[0].split("|"))
```

```
+--------------------+
|         col_explode|
+--------------------+
|1|John|Engineer|6...|
|2|Emma|Manager|75...|
|3|Michael|Analyst...|
|4|Sophia|Develope...|
|5|William|Designe...|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Please add a sample input and expected output and describe what are you trying to achieve at the end